# Formtastic, own :as input type

Tags: ruby, forms, input, formtastic

How I can add my own field types to formtastic ?

For exemple, I need to have a custom datetime input, and I want something like this:

```
<%= f.input :start_date , :as => :my_date %>
```

This obviously doesn't work because formtastic doesn't know the :my_date (only :boolean, :string, :datetime and so on...)

But how can I add additional input types ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a custom input method:

```
class MyCustomFormtasticFormBuilder < Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder
  protected
  def my_date_input(method, options)
    basic_input_helper(:text_field, :my_date, method, options)
  end
end
```

That's perfect for, say the new HTML5 input types. You use it like so:

```
<% form_form @model, :builder => MyCustomFormtasticFormBuilder  do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :my_date
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. My only addition is that you then need to configure Formtastic to us MyCustomFormtasticFormBuilder instead of Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder, which can be done in the config initializer supplied with Formtastic.

Answer (score 4):

> Don’t subclass Formtastic::FormBuilder anymore
>
> It was previously recommended in Formtastic 1.x to subclass Formtastic::FormBuilder to add
>   your own inputs. This is no longer recommended in Formtastic 2, and will not work as expected.

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

http://justinfrench.com/notebook/formtastic-2-preview-custom-inputs